# Помогите решить задачу?

Tags: python

Вывести список простых чисела в диапазоне d. Диапазон d вводит пользователь

Comment: Поможем. С чем конкретно возникла проблема?

Comment: сделать что бы числа отбирались именно простые

Answer (score 1):

1. диапазон чисел можно задать в 1 строчку, например так:

   ```
    left, right = map(int, input().split())
   ```
2. пройти по диапазону можно с использованием `for` и `range`:

   ```
    for value in range(left, right + 1):
   ```
3. проверить, что число является простым можно через деление на него всех чисел в диапазоне от `2` до `sqrt(value)` и проверкой остатка от деления - если остаток равен 0, то число не простое

   ```
    if value % div == 0
   ```

так что логика проверки такая:

1. устанавливаем флаг `is_prime = True` - проверяемое число простое
2. проверяем на делимость и если число делится без остатка устанавливаем флаг `is_prime = False` и прерываем цикл через `break`

Comment: а можно пожалуйста более простыми методами и функциями?

Comment: а куда уж проще? более простыми методами - это если использовать какие-то сторонние библиотеки, но разве именно это надо?

Comment: @Zhihar а можно же проверять не все делители "в диапазоне от 2 до sqrt(value)", а только простые до sqrt(value) (если рядом формировать список простых)?

Comment: @Jack_oS, можно, просто если число очень большое, а памяти очень мало некуда будет накопить список простых чисел, но в 2 раза расчёты сократить можно не рассматривая чётные числа, опять же некоторый пул простых чисел действительно накопить можно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```py
# Проверка простое ли число
def IsPrime(n): 
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n == 2
    d = 3
    while d * d <= n and n % d != 0:
        d += 2
    return d * d > n # Вернет True если простое

#Получаем диапазон
d1 = int(input("Начало:"))
d2 = int(input("Конец:"))

#Перебор в диапазоне
for i in range(d1, d2 + 1):
    if IsPrime(i): 
        print(f"{i} - простое")
```

Имхо тут главная сложность что есть простое число (сам гуглил...) остальное думаю недолжно быть проблемой.